# Find correlation in large dataset

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, large-data

I have a huge dataset. We are talking about 100 3D matrices with 121x145x121 cells. Any cell has a value between 0 and 1, and I need a way to cluster these cells according to their correlation. The problem is the dataset is too big for any algorithm I know; even using just half of it (any matrix is a MRI scan of a brain) we have around 400 billion pairs. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, I am programming in MATLAB.

Comment: What kind of correlation are you talking about? Can you define what "correlation" means in the context of the data?

Comment: I have to ask: how do the cells "correlate"? Is it just a number that matches or something more complicated?

Comment: Too bad you're using MATLAB. I know MATLAB specializes in matrix math, but you might get better performance out of a compiled app, tailored specifically for your problem

Comment: @VivinPaliath Any correlation would work; but for love of simplicity we can assume linear correlations. You can think at the problem in this way: I have 100 3D matrices, so any cell (e.g., 70-50-70) can be thought as an array of values (the values of all the cells with that position among the 100 matrices). So what I need is a way to calculate correlation between all these 'arrays', so that I know that cell 60-70-60 is highly correlated with cell 61-70-60. This should clarify my problem (for Frecklefoot as well).

Comment: So you are comparing 100 3D matrices of 121x145x121 cells with each other to see if cells in each of the matrices are correlated with others? So `[61, 70, 60]` will contain 100 values (zeroes or ones) representing the value for that cell for each of the 100 arrays?

Comment: If the problem is that your data doesn't fit in memory, then you can use something like a [memmapfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html)

Comment: @VivinPaliath Yep: every matrix is a MRI scan and every cell is the quantity of grey matter in that cell. I want to which voxels (=cells) are correlated with each other. So let's say that among all the subject the cell [01, 01, 01] = 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, ..., 0.9 and the cell [02, 01, 01] = 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, ..., 0.8, these cells are clearly correlated with each other.

Comment: Not sure if you want to know which matrices are grouped or what areas of space are clustered for all the matrices. Your question seems to be the latter; your reply to Vivn seems to be the former?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first step I would be tempted to try [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

This appears in the Matlab statistics toolbox as the function [kmeans](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/kmeans.html).

In this algorithm you only end up computing the distances between the K current centres and the data, so the number of pairs is much smaller than comparing all choices.

In Matlab, I've also found that the speed of the operation can be quite dependent on the organisation of your matrix (due to memory caching and optimisation issues).  I would recommend transforming your 3d matrices so that the columns (held together in memory) correspond to the 100 values for a particular cell.

This can be done with the [permute function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/permute.html).

Comment: Native kmeans function does not support 3D clustering, unfortunately. I can 'scroll' the matrices but this will again takes ages. I am not actually searching for an algorithm: an heuristic would do the job as well, if I could find any.

Comment: Do you have enough memory to use reshape to turn it from multiple 3d matrices to a single 2d matrix? (Of size n*m with n=100 and m=121x145x121)

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I am quite sure I am not. I can give it a shot but we are still talking about an operation that may take months (rearranging 2122945 elements...!).

Answer (score 0):

Try a weighted [K-means++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means++) clustering algorithm. Create one matrix of the sum of values for all the 100 input matrices at every point to produce one "grey scale" matrix, then adjust the K-means++ algorithm to work with weighted, (wt), values.

In the initialization phase choose one new data point at random as a new center, using a weighted probability distribution where a point x is chosen with probability proportional to D(X)^2 x wt^2 .

The [assignment step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means#Standard_algorithm) should be okay, but when computing the centroids in the update step adjust the formula to account for the weights. (Or use the same formula but each point is used wt times).

You may not be able to use a library function to do this but you start with a 100 fold decrease in number of points and matrices to work with.